# reCAPTCHA detects c# webbrowser

Tags: java, c#, selenium, webbrowser-control, recaptcha

I want to make a small browser in my application (windows/c#) and when I meet reCAPTCHA in some websites it just detects me as a bot (I keep trying to solve it but I can't because when I go to the audio session they tell me as the pic bellow), but I want to open a small browser to my users when they can navigate. 
Can anyone help me please how to make my browser like chrome or Firefox maybe? 
Thanks in advance .

[image]

Comment: are you using headless ?

Comment: no , not selenium webdriver it's the webbrowser control c# winforms

Comment: if you control the application try https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq#id-like-to-run-automated-tests-with-recaptcha-v2-what-should-i-do

Comment: okay , i'll try it now .

Comment: i'm not tying to use reCAPTCHA for my website ... i just want to make a regular browser for my users to navigate websites and i used webbrowser c# control but it appears that my browser is not allowed to pass recaptcha like when my user try to solve the recaptcha manually "they r humans" they get an endless loop pics :/ i just don't know why maybe i have to set the browser name and version or i don't know :/ :( .